# Android: copy sqlite from assets before Gingerbread

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a sqlite db in assets folder and, for the first launch of my app, I copy it to path "data/data/databases".

This works fine on all devices from Gingerbread, but for older versions I get a table not found exception when I query the db. In fact the db in databases folder is empty. It only contains an android_metadata table.

Here the two methods I use to copy the db:

```
 public static void copyDBInMemoryIfNeeded(Context ctx, String pkgName) {
    try {
        String destPath = ctx.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath() + "/databases";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();
            copyDBInMemory(ctx.getAssets().open("mydb.sqlite"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void copyDBInMemory(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    // ---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

and here my DBAdapter class:

```
public class DBAdapter {    

final Context context;
DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper= new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}                                                                                              }
```

Comment: how big is your sql file in assets folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended un splitting the database with HJSplit and then putting the parts on assets folder. Then I copy the db in "data/data/databases" in this way:

```
    private static void copyDataBase(Context ctx, FileOutputStream os) throws IOException {
    AssetManager am = ctx.getAssets();
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int r;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        InputStream is = am.open("mydb.sqlite.00" + i);
        while ((r = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, r);
        }
        is.close();
    }
    os.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android 2.2 and below there is something which you should consider while using sqlite files in assets folder. File bigger than 1MB won't be able to be copied in your apps private database folder. Not sure if this is a bug or something else, but if you want to use your database, you can create the whole database schema in your database helper.

**Workaround:** Not sure if this is a good option, but it works in my situation with 12MB sqlite database, just remove `.sqlite` , `.db` or any kind of database extensions  from your file's name and it should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, for the clarification! I tried your workaround but unfortunately it doesn't work for me... I'll try to split my db in different files and put them in assets folder.

Comment: Try to put some other file extension if you want, I was trying once with .mp3 and it did work.